# User Agent detection for iPad not working. C#

Tags: c#, ipad, user-agent

I have an app that renders videos as a thumbnail.  For iPad users we want to suppress the video so I in my code I am trying to detect if the user is on an ipad via userAgent string.  It the user agent string contains "ipad" I just return out of the method and not render the video link.

```
userAgent = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();
if (userAgent.Contains("ipad")) return;
```

The issue I am seeing is this.  If I force my browser (Chrome) to UserAgent iPad using User Agent Switcher plugin, it works as expected but the same code on the actual iPad device does not work (I still see the videos).

Is there something else I need to look for?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: is the device running Chrome or a different browser..?

Comment: take a look at this example / Tutorial- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231869-aspnet-c%23-mobile-browser-detection-for-html5-video/

Comment: As it turns out it was an issue with iPad caching the old page.  Once I was able to get the cache cleared (which I tried a couple times), it is working as expected now.